# FirebaseMessagingService - How to update Database or SharedPreferences from the background?

Tags: android, database, firebase, sharedpreferences, firebase-notifications

I am trying to update the app database after receiving a push notification from Firebase Console. It works when the app is running, but when the app is in the background or process is killed, I can't change the data in SharedPreferences.

But sending notification with `NotificationManager` is working. Is there any way to update database when retrieving push notification from Firebase?

```
 private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EventListActivityDrawerNewMenu.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}

private void saveDataToPreferences(String data) {
    Context context = this;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(UpdateDataService.MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(UpdateDataService.MY_PREFS_NAME, data);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    saveDataToPreferences(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've sold the problem. Firebase has two types of push notifications: displayed and data messages. And only data messages could wake up your service to update database. You can not create data message from firebase console, you can send it only by post request on url:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Body:

```
{
"data": {
    "data" : "some message",
    "other_key" : true
 },
"registration_ids": ["here your user token", "another user token"]}
```

Headers:

- Key: Content-Type, Value: application/json
- Key: Authorization, Value: key=your-server-key